# Promise truncate data

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise passing data by `then` and the data has been truncated. there are any limit of bytes of data to pass over a promise?

```
return this.conexao
            .requestSend(url, locacoesJson)
            .then(data=>{
                //data is not complete here  
             });
```

I'm doing anything wrong?

```
requestSend(url, json){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        try{
            const request = net.request(url);

            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            request.on('response', (response) => {
                response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    const data = `${chunk}`;            

                    if(response.statusCode == 200)  
                        resolve(data);
                    else
                        reject(data);
                });

                response.on('error', (error) => {
                    reject(`${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
                })
            });
            request.write(json, (teste) => {})
            request.end();
        }catch(e){
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does "is not complete" mean?

Comment: And what's the purpose of doing ```const data = `${chunk}`;```?

Comment: the data is a big json, and has been split at this point / i'm using electron chunk is from documentation

Comment: at here `if(response.statusCode == 200)  resolve(data);` my data is complete

Comment: Your code for handling the chunks makes no sense. You're not assembling the chunks together - you're just resolving the promise with the value of the first chunk. That's why your data is truncated. It's not because of a limitation in promises. I also fail to see the purpose of the line ``const data = `${chunk}`;``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are not to blame here. The issue is that you are not handling the chunking at all and resolving the promise with the contents of the first chunk.

You need to assemble the chunks until you have them all, and *then* resolve the promise. Without being familiar with the API you're using, I think it would be something like this:

```
requestSend(url, json){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        const request = net.request(url);

        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.on('response', (response) => {
            let data = '';

            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            response.on('error', (error) => {
                reject(`${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
            });

            response.on('aborted', () => reject('Request aborted'));

            response.on('end' () => {
                if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject(data);
                }
            });
        });
        request.write(json, (teste) => {})
        request.end();
    });
}
```

Note that I've removed the `try-catch` because it was redundant.

Comment: thanks man, it's worked!! but it's never go to `response.on('end' () => {`, do you know why?

Comment: sorry, working perfect now, I've put `on('data'` at last